# EasyOCR image preprocessing?

Tags: ocr, image-preprocessing, easyocr

Does easyOCR do image preprocessing? There are saying on the GitHub page that there are doing a "pre process" [1](https://github.com/JaidedAI/EasyOCR#implementation-roadmap), but i don't know what this means.